# When trying to access local private ip, the browser redirects to projectname.local:8080?

Tags: apache, vagrant, hosts

In my hosts file I have myproject.local using 199.199.99.99. I'm using Vagrant with a private ip of 199.199.99.99 and when I visit myproject.local in the browser it works fine. But sometimes it will take too long to connect or I will accidentally refresh the page before Vagrant is up and the browser redirects me to myproject.local:8080 no matter what...Unless I go clear the browser cache, then it will work again. It's a pain having to clear the cache every time this happens. Is there anyway to stop it from redirecting me?

Answer (score 0):

199.199.99.99 isn't a [private IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). Try update your vagrantfile with a `forwarded_ports` configuration (if haven't already), and replace your `static IP` with a non-conflicting private IP address.

On my box, it looks something like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
end
```